# Select portion of articles

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an article structure, where an article can be a main article or a sub article. I only want the sub articles and main articles that does not have any sub articles. An article is a subarticle if its ArticleNo != MainArticleNo.

Example, here I want Article1-1 and Article2

```
Article1 = main article
Article1-1 = sub article of Article1

Article2 = main article with no sub articles
```

Comment: It's not clear what structure you have on your table. Can you add the table's DDL?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result that really help.

Comment: Is it SQL server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `EXISTS` query to check if article has children:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE MainArticleNo <> ArticleNo
OR NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM articles AS subarticles
    WHERE subarticles.MainArticleNo = articles.ArticleNo
)
```